# How to change directory using hosted runner via Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a simple pipeline where I just want to navigate to a specific folder on the server hosting the runner.

My runner is online, I added the host in the SSH Keys section, and my step is:

```
  - step:
      name: 'Write log to server'
      services:
        - docker
      runs-on:
        - self.hosted
        - linux
      script:
        - export HOST_PROJECT_PATH=/home/project/myproject
        - ls -a
        - cd $HOST_PROJECT_PATH // folder not found but exists
```

The `ls -a` shows the content of my Bitbucket repository, and I can't cd to an existing directory (directory exists on the server).

Can I do it using pipeline & runner ? Do I need to use an other service ? Can't find any example or documentation.

Comment: Have you solved it?. I think you should add a volume on the runner, docker run [all existing parameters] -v /mydir:/mydir -e WORKING_DIRECTORY=/mydir [https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-and-use-runners-for-linux/]